# Display an xml value when it can contain a value as well as a reference

Tags: xslt, reference, display

How do I display an xml value when it can contain a value as well as a reference?

For example I try to list characteristics from a generated XML. The first entry contains data in the format 'text'. The second value as well but this is listed as a reference to the former characteristic.

```
<characteristicTypes>
  <characteristictype>
    <number>1</number>
    <format>TEXT</format>
    <name>Address</name>
  </characteristictype>
  <characteristictype>
    <number>2</number>
    <format reference="../../characteristictype/format"/>
    <name>Description</name>
  </characteristictype>
<characteristicTypes>
```

I would like to display both of them as follows:

1. Characteristic 1

   - Format: text
   - Name: Address
2. Characteristic 2

   - Format: text
   - Name: Description

When I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="format"/>
```

The first entry contains the correct value, but the second is empty:

1. Characteristic 1

   - Format: text
   - Name: Address
2. Characteristic 2

   - Format:
   - Name: Description

Comment: Does your XML really contain XPath expressions that need to be evaluated? If so, you will need a processor that supports either XSLT 3.0 or and some sort of an `evaluate()` extension function. -- Note also that the given expression refers not only to `<format>TEXT</format>` but also to itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
<xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::characteristicTypes/characteristictype/format"/>
```

The use of `preceding-sibling` will provide access to the previous node.